# SQL Server Clear transaction log

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I have a database that is in Full Recovery Mode that I restored from a backup file

Now I want to clear/truncate the transaction log file.
How I can do this.

Step 1 I tried to backup the transaction log using

```
BACKUP LOG [test] TO  DISK
```

but I get error:

> BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

So what I should do to clear the transition log if I want to keep the database in Full Recovery Mode

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to do this but you can do `ALTER DATABASE [test] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE; ALTER DATABASE [test] SET RECOVERY FULL;` The whole point of using Full recovery is to keep the backup chain intact, don't do this if you want to be able to restore from a new backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

Means your database is in "pseudo-full" recovery, and until someone takes a full backup there's no way or need to take log backups, and the log will be still be truncated after each checkpoint, just like in the SIMPLE recovery model.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using shrink database files from database menus.

Another is using some scripting(change dbname to your database name):

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
GO  
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (dbname_Log,10);  
GO  
-- Reset the database recovery model.  
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```